# React Native - Image disappears, when the alert shows up

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting this strange issue, whenever the Alert appears on my page, the image gets disappeared. And this is only happening for iOS.

Here is my code for showing Alert:

```
Alert.alert(
 "Success",
 responseData.message,
 [
  { text: "Okay", onPress: () => this.props.navigation.goBack() }
 ],
);
```

Code for showing image:

```
<Image
 style={{ width: normalize(70), height: normalize(70), borderRadius: 100, position: 'absolute', borderColor: 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', borderWidth: 1, }}
 source={{ uri: this.state.contactInfo.profilePicUrl }}
 />
```

Attached screenshot for reference:

1. When there is an image:

[image: When there is an image]

2. When the alert shows up, the image is gone:

[image: When the alert shows up]

Any idea why is this happening?

**UPDATE 1:** The issue is happening only in case or images coming from URL.

Comment: no idea but try adding the Image style 'elevation: 1'

Comment: Hey did you ever figure it out? I'm getting a similar issue with images randomly disappearing and re-appearing.